# Find by element issue in selinum

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am new to selenium and doing some automation using python. I am  trying to find element by xpath in below html code

```
(/input[@id='spForm:providerNumberInput']")
```

but I am getting error. Not sure what is wrong?

### Error

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/input[@id='spForm:providerNumberInput']"}

### HTML CODE

```html
<input id="spForm:providerNumberInput" name="spForm:providerNumberInput" type="text" value="" maxlength="10" size="10" class="inputText">
```

Comment: Please provide HTML of the page you are automating and your code trials.

Comment: We do not have enough information to answer your question. See [What should a 'minimal, reproducible example' include for problems with automating web browsers using Selenium?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405791).

Answer (score 0):

try to use first:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='spForm:providerNumberInput']")
```

try to find by class:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='inputText']")
```

or by name, id

Comment: I tried all types and still did not work.

Comment: @Bobby then, please provide part of the HTML or page would be better

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://XXXX.CCCC.com/providers/web/login")

driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("XXXXXX")
driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("XXXXX")
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="app"]/div/main/div/div[1]/div/main/div/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/form/button').click()
time.sleep(3)
sucess = driver.current_url
if sucess != 'https://XXXXX.XXXXX.com/providers/web/home?WAIEAI_CODE=SUCCESS_LOGIN&WAIEAI_MSG=Authentication%20successful.':
     driver.close()
else:
     driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@href="/XXXX/web/eligibility/health-XXXXX"]').click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@name="spForm:providerNumberInput"]')
```

I tried to find the element in last step by name, id but it's keep failing with element not found.

Answer (score 0):

```
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='spForm:providerNumberInput']")
```

If this doesn't work check if the element is in a iframe.